# IOS/Objective-C: Change tint of an image view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to change the color of an image view when the user touches it.  I don't need it to change a great deal.  However, I would like it to change to a shade of blue.  I found the following code to change the gradient but it is not having any effect.  I don't need a gradient, actually, only a tint.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
 UIView *snapshot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        snapshot.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
          CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

        gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

        [snapshot.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Comment: `someView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and non-intrusive way is to add a translucent overlay to your image view. This can then be shown and hidden as the button is pressed and released.

```
- (void)indicatedImageViewPressed:(UIImageView *)imageView on:(BOOL)on {
    UIView *overlay = [imageView viewWithTag:1]; // See if already created
    if (overlay == nil) {
        overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.bounds];
        overlay.tag = 1; // Mark view to find it next time
        overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.3]; // Your color overlay goes here
        [imageView addSubview:overlay];
    }
    overlay.hidden = !on;
}
```

Comment: I changed the imageView in the signature to UIView and it worked like a charm so no need to change view to imageview.

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving the UIImage a tint

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Or any color really you'd like would work
imageView.image = newImage;
```

And then changing that tint when the user touches the image using a tap gesture recognizer

Comment: I am starting with a UIView, not an image.  Can I still use this?  Also by newImage do you mean image in the first line?

Comment: You are starting with a UIView but you are allocating it as a UIImageView.
If you are actually using a UIView, how are you going to display the image?

Comment: The view gets moved around a lot as part of some other code.  When I tried, snapshot.image I get no property image found on snapshot.  I am reluctant to change snapshot to an actual UIImage as various things happen to it in the other code.