# Add transparent overlay as subview of `uiimageview`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, addsubview

I have a UITable with custom cells, each of which has a `uiimage`. When I highlight the cell, the image is not getting highlighted.

To highlight the cell's image, when I select a cell in my table, `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` is called. In that method, I change the background color of the cell. I also call a method, `indicatedImageViewPressed`, [which I got from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979191/ios-objective-c-change-tint-of-an-image-view), to add an overlay to the image of the cell.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Add your Colour.

    SpeciesCell* speciesCell = (SpeciesCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    speciesCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000];
    speciesCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000];
    speciesCell.speciesImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000];
    [self indicatedImageViewPressed:speciesCell.imageView on:YES];
}

- (void)indicatedImageViewPressed:(UIImageView *)imageView on:(BOOL)on {
    UIView *overlay = [imageView viewWithTag:1]; // See if already created
    if (overlay == nil) {
        overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];
        overlay.tag = 1; // Mark view to find it next time
        overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000]; // Your color overlay goes here
        [imageView addSubview:overlay];
        [imageView bringSubviewToFront:overlay];
    }
    overlay.hidden = !on;
}
```

However, the cell's image does not change. No overlay is added. I tried `bringSubviewToFront` to make sure the overlay wasn't obscured by some other view, but it still doesn't work.

UPDATE: I am able to add a border width/color to `speciesCell.speciesImage`

Comment: just for debugging purpose add border width and border color red to speciesCell.speciesImage inside didHighlightRowAtIndexPath method and let me know if It is showing border on image or not

Comment: @MuhammedIrfan border does show up on speciesCell.speciesImage!

Comment: hmm thats an issue

Comment: you see your adding layer code has no issue with it

Comment: @Matt In my opinion, changing `alpha` or `opacity` of image is an easier way and you won't get this issue.

Comment: @trungduc is there a way to make the highlight of the table cell match the alpha of the uiimageview? I'm not against using alpha/opactiy, I was adding a UIView because I could specify its background color to be the same as the cell's background color (`[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000]`)

Comment: @Matt i dont think it’s hard. Try to set opacity of imageView to 0.17. If it’s still not same change it a little until it’s perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
speciesCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000];
speciesCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000];
speciesCell.speciesImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.17 alpha:1.000];
```

replace this with below code:

```
 SpeciesCell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Comment: but I don't want it to be clear color, I want a slight grey, transparent overlay...

Comment: matt first time i didnt get what you want do with your overlay try this definitely work

Comment: i think he want to change backgroundcolor of cell when click on uitableviewcell- @trungduc